# Get date just from Weekday with Luxon in javascript/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, luxon

I am using the Luxon package in Node JS and I need to get a date string formatted like this: (06.09. Monday) where '06' is the day of the month and '09' is the month.
Is there a way to get the get the date formatted like this just from entering the Weekday (like Monday) with Luxon?

Ask if my question is unclear.

Comment: Do you mean nearest Monday from today?

Answer (score 1):

```js
DateTime.now().toFormat("dd.MM (cccc)") //=> '16.09 (Thursday)'
```

Comment: For those wondering where these characters are from: https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax